# Should javascript Class methods decide if they execute or should the callee make the decision to call or not?

Tags: javascript, architecture

I am implementing a simple Class method that calls an endpoint and return the request result. However there is some business logic that is needed to determine if this endpoint is called at all. Since I can pass application state around should I pass into the method the state that is evaluated to determine if the endpoint is called, or should it be the responsibility of the caller to decide if the endpoint method is called at all?

Benefit of the method deciding is the logic is in one place, the down side is the method creates an API that is somewhat unpredictable; the caller asks for an HTTP call which may or may not be made outside of the caller's control.

Answer (score 0):

About down side, I guess its normal to expect fail request.
Method should decide to call or not according class internal state.
It has to return Promise to indicate that endpoint call may not be executed.